# How do I differentiate to what they have given?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Given that  $y = \dfrac{x^3 - 5x}{\sqrt{x}}$, show that $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$= $\dfrac{5(x^2 - 1)}{2 \sqrt{x}}$

(Posted from ``answer'' below: I get as far as  $\dfrac{dy}{dx}= \dfrac {5}{2}x^\frac {3}{2}  - \dfrac {5}{2}x^\frac{-1}{2}$  but struggling with the first fraction.)

I am just getting to grips with the formatting so hope that is clear! 
Many thanks

Comment: Well, there are two options. You can either use the quotient rule, or you can simplify the first expression using standard exponent rules to find $y = x^{5/2} - 5x^{1/2}$ and differentiate as you normally would. Which of these are you more comfortable with?

Comment: I've been using the standard rules method. Thanks for reply.

Comment: @Andros, the answer is $\dfrac{5(x^2-1)}{2\sqrt{x}}$.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar, Thanks for replying so far, sorry for confusion. But how did you get that answer by using standard exponent rules on the above?

Comment: @Andros The product rule; see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the quotient rule:
$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)=\dfrac{g(x)f^\prime(x)-f(x)g^\prime(x)}{(g(x))^2}$$
With $f(x)=x^3-5x$, and $g(x)=\sqrt{x}$.

Alternatively, use the product rule by realizing that $\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x}}=\sqrt{x}$:
$$\dfrac{d}{dx}(f(x)g(x))=f^\prime(x)g(x)+f(x)g^\prime(x)$$
With $f(x)=x^2-5$, and $g(x)=\sqrt{x}$.

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{(3x^2-5)\sqrt{x}-\frac{x^3-5x}{2\sqrt{x}}}{x}=\frac{3x^2-5}{\sqrt{x}}-\frac{x^2-5}{2\sqrt{x}}=\frac{5(x^2-1)}{2\sqrt{x}}$

Comment: Do not disclose the answer - let the OP explore somethings by himself.